# How to slice numpy array starting from x-n elements?

Tags: python, numpy, slice

If i have a numpy array:

```
arr = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
x = 3 # index
n = 5
m = 2
```

Is there a way to get an output like this?

```
output: np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])
```

We start at 4 which is index `x=3`. The output consists of `n=5` elements before said index, but does not wrap around (doesn't go beyond the 1 in this case). And also consists of `m=2` elements after said index.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
x = 3
n = 5
m = 2
arr[max(0, x-n):x+m+1]
# array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
```